# How to manage big database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a database of analytic information.
my database as is below.

1. Table Name: display_page. here we store data about page when customer(of our user) create an order.(page has multiple sections). the table has 12 Million rows

[image]

2. element_impression. Here we store data about each section. (if the page has 5 sections we insert 5 rows for it. we have 10 unique sections and each will be repeated on page). the table has 45 Million rows
   [image]
3. element_clicks. Here we store data about click over the section means when someone clicks on any section of the page we store the data into clicks table.
   the table has 1.52 Million rows

[image]

Everything is worked fine since last year. But now it will create an issue when trying to fetch data according to the date range.

in future it will become 10X more from this stage. Please suggest with the best way to handle it.

Comment: Afraid to ask but, do you have proper indexation?

Comment: @Carlos I am trying to create index too but I am getting an error operation will take long time

Comment: @Sanchin Sarola Then I suggest you to search and ask about that error as It is the solution to your approach.

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí it takes a long time because of data size if I create an index on other table expect impression then its create